# Error "comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types" encountered in metafor

Tags: r, metadata

I'm very new to r and trying to run a multi-level meta analysis using pre-calculated effect sizes. The data file can be accessed via this link:[testrunfile](https://osf.io/urg7q/)

The script I used as a first step to fit the model was:

```r
res <- rma.mv (yi = es_r, v = var, data = testrun, method = "REML", level = 95, digits = 7, slab = ref, random = ~ 1 | samp_id)
```

But I keep getting this error:

`Error in verbose > 2 :  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types`

Could someone help give me a hand to help me understand what this error message means and where did I go wrong with the script?
Many thanks!